# Linq Join Two Repository Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two Repository Stock and Inventory ,Both have Get , Insert ,Update ,delete Methods

```
private IStockService _stockService;
private IInventoryService _inventoryService;
public StockController(IStockService StockService, IInventoryService InventoryService)
{
    _stockService = StockService;
    _inventoryService = InventoryService;
}
```

InterFace is

```
public interface IStockService
    {
        IEnumerable<Stock> GetStock();

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        IEnumerable<Stock> GetStock(Func<Stock, bool> where);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="id"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        Stock GetStockById(int id);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objStock"></param>
        void InsertStock(Stock objStock);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objStock"></param>
        void UpdateStock(Stock objStock);

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="objStock"></param>
        void DeleteStock(Stock objStock);
    }
```

I Want To Join Two Repository Using Linq Query eg: from stock in _stock JOIN etc

Comment: What keeps you from doing what you describe?

Comment: Can you tell me how to join both repositories to one..

Comment: You dont `.Join` on 2 repositories. You would instead `.Join` on either 2 `IQueryable`'s, or 2 in memory `IEnumerable`'s. So return your data, and join the 2 `IEnumerable`'s

Comment: We have no idea how your entities are related, and what type of ORM you're using, and if there are any navigation properties, and so on and so forth. From what I do see, I'm afraid that you already made a couple of disputable design decisions that need refactoring rather than trying to work around the impediments they cause.

Answer (score 0):

You should join on GetStock() method of the first repository and ... method of the second repository with their equals fields.

```
Var result1 = repo.getstock();
Var result2 = repo2.yourMethodName();
```

And join with linq on result1 and result2